# Расположение объектов внутри блока справа

Tags: html, css

Есть: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При добавлении `float: right;` к блоку с логотипами, логотипы смещаются вправо вниз. Конечно можно использовать `margin-top` с отрицательным значением, но не хотелось бы.

Comment: Так вы добавьте код, по картинкам как понять что там у вас

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, как вариант :)

```css
.bg {
  /*Это все, что вам нужно*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  /*А это для красоты*/
  background: #3A2A7E;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"> 
    <div class="text">Текст</div>
    <div class="image">Иконки</div>
</div>
```